# How to replace certain value with the value in the different columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here below is the dataframe that iam working with:

```
 sn.     code    code2    code3
 1       AB       kd       kj
 2       EX       kf       li
 3       EX       ka       lt
 4       EX       n/a      ap
```

Desired is to replace EX in code with the value from code2 else code3.

```
 sn.     code    code2    code3
 1       AB       kd       kj
 2       kf       kf       li
 3       ka       ka       lt
 4       ap       n/a      ap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am not a big fan of complex one-line expressions I'd go like this:

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    c = row['code']
    c2 = row['code2']
    c3 = row['code3']
    if(c=='EX' and c2):
        c = row['code2']
    elif(c3):
        c = c3
    row['code'] = c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.loc[df['code'].eq('EX'), 'code'] = df[['code2','code3']].bfill(1)['code2']
```